# Change User Agent reported by HTML5

Tags: php, html, user-agent

I don't know if this is possible, but I am trying to find a work around for it.

I currently have an application for Windows, Android, and iOS that communicates with an online database via a PHP script. As **A PART** of my security I have the application use a unique user agent when communicating with this PHP script, so I check if the user agent is from that application before running the script. If it is not, then I redirect to a 404 page. This is to prevent URL manipulation in the browser.

Now my issue, I want to make an HTML5 version of this application, but the HTML5 version of the application reports the browsers user agent so it gets blocked. Is there a way to make an HTML5 app broadcast a different user agent than the browser?

Comment: So _any other_ client can breach your so called “security”, as long as it sends that specific user agent …?

Comment: There is more security beyond that, I said this is A PART of it. This is THE PART that is giving me issues with an HTML5 version.

Comment: It might be possible with a custom browser plugin but I doubt it, the user agent is hard coded into the browser. It certainly cant be in in js if that's what you were hoping. I think you need to re-think your strategy

Comment: _“I said this is A PART of it”_ – a useless part at that. Anyway, I think the only circumstances that would allow you to change it would be AJAX requests, where you can specify additional headers yourself. Of course, anyone looking at the script source could see it there …